# .Net Core - How to log GC collection to console?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, garbage-collection

On Full Visual Studio, when you start debugging an app, a side bar appears and the memory consumption chart has a yellow "diamond" mark that signifies that a GC Collection has happened. Im using VS for Mac and such instrumentation is not available.

I would like to know if there's a way to log the GC activities on the console so I can analyse it.

Comment: Use [dotnet diagnostic tools CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/design-docs/dotnet-tools.md).You can collect *trace* and open it in PerfView.

Comment: Seems like you could use the new .Net Core [`EventPipes` feature](https://medium.com/criteo-labs/spying-on-net-garbage-collector-with-net-core-eventpipes-9f2a986d5705).

Comment: Maybe you can try to subscribe to [Garbage Collection ETW Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/garbage-collection-etw-events).

Comment: @KyleWang any idea on how to subscribe to them? they seem to be what I need, but I couldn't figure out how to catch them

Comment: @Leonardo Normally use  [Logman and Xperf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/controlling-logging?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to achieve it.

Comment: @KyleWang this doesn't seem to work out of windows... or I miss-interpreted something?

Comment: I don't think you missed anything. ETW literally means Event Tracing for Windows.